# Orbeon form: Disable form fields after clicking "Submit"

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to configure "Send" process to set all fields to readonly, but it didn't work. Here is my configuration in properties.xml:

```
        <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*">
            require-valid
            then save
            then success-message("save-success")
            then xf:setvalue(ref = "//*[xf:readonly]", value = "true()")
        </property>
```

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the "readonly-ness", in an imperative imperative way, with a `xf:setvalue`. Instead, the "readonly-ness" is define in a declarative way. In your case, I would recommend that:

1. When the form is submitted, you change the stage of the form, say to "submitted". In your process, you can do so with ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner#set-workflow-stage)):

   ```
    set-workflow-stage(name = "submitted")
   ```
2. In Form Builder, you use a form level formula ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/form-settings#formulas)) to declare that the whole form is readonly if the stage is "submitted". The formula will look like:

   ```
    fr:workflow-stage-value() = 'submitted'
   ```

Also see the blog post [New workflow capabilities in Orbeon Forms 2020.1](https://blog.orbeon.com/2021/01/new-workflow-capabilities-in-orbeon.html).

Comment: Thanks @avernet, Do we have any option to apply this  fr:workflow-stage-value() = 'submitted' by default for every forms builder in the system?

Comment: @Tien yes you can, since this is done in a process, which is defined in your `properties-local.xml`, for instance using a property name like `oxf.fr.detail.process.submit.*.*`, where the `*.*` indicates that this process applies to all the apps and all the forms. You can find more about this in the section [Wildcards in properties](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties#wildcards-in-properties).

Comment: Hi @avernet, Is it possible to set default value for a form builder readonly-formula on creating?

I'm trying with something like:
    
<property
as="xs:anyURI"
name="oxf.fr.detail.readonly.formula"
value="fr:workflow-stage-value() = 'submitted'"/>

Comment: @Tien I guess you are trying to avoid having to have to set, for every form, that the whole form is readonly if ` fr:workflow-stage-value() = 'submitted'`. Unfortunately, at this point, this can't be defined in the properties, but only in Form Builder. -Alex

Comment: @Tien But what you are suggesting makes sense. I've created a request for enhancement for this: [#4931](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4931). -Alex

Comment: thanks a lot for your great supports.
Then, I'm trying to call API to update form builder one by one with this payload:

        <xxf:uuid>943a44aa9644791d4acb18c505f621b6dd242c9a</xxf:uuid>
        <xxf:sequence>9</xxf:sequence>
        <xxf:action>
            <xxf:event name="xxforms-value" source-control-id="dialog-form-settings≡xf-1586≡xf-1807≡xf-2168≡xpath-textarea">
                <xxf:property name="value">fr:workflow-stage-value() = 'submitted'</xxf:property>

Is that possible and what should I input for <xxf:sequence>

Comment: @Tien You can do this with the [background API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/other-apis/run-form-background). -Alex

Comment: It looks like this approach just work once. When the form instance is submitted and readonly, If I close the browser and open the form instance again, it will be back to edit mode as normally

Comment: @Tien Mmh… you've set the workflow stage to `submitted`, set the form to read-only when the workflow stage is `submitted`, open the form and it is readonly, but if you open it again (just reload the page?), you're saying that it isn't readonly anymore? If so, has the workflow stage changed in meantime, somehow? -Alex

Comment: yes this is the correct case. I have checked table: orbeon_i_current (postgres) and saw all stage cells have null values. It looks like it can't save stage to the database. <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*">
        save()
        then set-workflow-stage(name = "submitted")
        then success-message("save-success")
 </property>

Comment: I got the issue. we should save after set workstage

Comment: @Tien Yes, you do need to save the data; running `set-workflow-stage(name = "submitted")` just sets the workflow stage in the "live data". I'm glad you found this out, and thanks for the update. -Alex